# How to show queue position?

Tags: usability, website-design, web-app

I'm working on a site where users can place bids on an item but there are multiple items for sale, so the user gets put in a queue. The highest bidder in the moment wins then we go to person below them. I'm really trying to make it clear that it's not just the highest bidder who wins. It can be anyone, just depends on the timing.

Can I get some guidance on how I can go about showing this?

Comment: Is there a time delay in between the assignment of items to bids? The process is made for all items at once, or once an item is set the process continues with the second item, etc.?

Comment: @alvaro once an item is set the process continues with the second item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what **users are biding for is the order in which they will receive the item**. So I guess this is what creates confusion because users might think they are bidding for the item itself.

```
50 items

1st Position in queue ($100)
2nd-3rd Position in queue ($80)
4th-6th Position in queue ($60) [Bid $20 more to go up one step in the queue]
...
50th Position in queue ($10)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can simply use a number to indicate which place in the queue someone is taking, I would recommend making a thin line on the right with dots on it. The user's position is indicated by a dot which is larger or of a different colour. Under that is a counter which shows the precise position.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a leaderboard like view where you list the bids for the product in an [Expansion Panel](https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html)-like fashion. You could list all the users who have made a particular bid when the user expands a particular panel with the users placed in the order in which they placed the bid.